# How to make a QPushButton the same dimensions as its background-image?

Tags: qt, button, stylesheet, background-image

I have a QPushButton on my main window:

```
practiceButton_ = new QPushButton(this);
practiceButton_->setText(_("Practice"));
practiceButton_->setObjectName("practiceButton");
```

Then I associate some style with it:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QPushButton#practiceButton { background-image: url('myfile.png'); padding:0; margin:0; border:none; }");
```

The background image shows up and it looks like the style is applied successfully, however the button is smaller than the background image. How can I make it resize to fit its background image?

If it cannot be done automatically, is it possible to access the style applied to the button somewhere, and resize the button based on it? I'd just like to avoid hard-coding the values if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    pushButton.resize( QImage( "filename.png" ).size() );
```

Comment: Of course, this isn't very efficient--loading a png just to get its size--but the rest is an exercise left for the reader.

Comment: What if the user changes the image name to something else in the CSS?

Comment: Well I've been trying things out a bit with little success. I think the issue is that there's a difference between a background image and an icon. Your solution is probably best, although it does require the user to enter repeat information. Another solution might be to rethink use of style sheets in this case and go with a QConfig type of solution (you can use both: style for the style, config for the icon set). Other solutions might be to try to get the background image of the push button and get its size (one hack would be parsing qApp->styleSheet() and doing what I've shown above).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just figured out that the width and height can be set in the CSS itself, which is probably the right way to do it:

```
QPushButton#practiceButton {
    background-image: url('NavigationButtonUp.png');
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
    width: 194px;
    height: 40px;
}
```